# Can't click on drop down/context menus in Firefox on tablet

Tags: tablet, windows-8-preview

On my Acer Iconia W500 with Windows Developer Preview 32-bit, I am unable to touch the context and drop down menus.  The browser acts as if the menu was not shown in the first place and instead "clicks" whatever is directly underneath the menu option I am trying to click.

When I use an actual mouse, the drop down menus work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: close as too localised — we’ve had two more betas by now